# <div> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using some jQuery from [this site](http://igoo.co.uk/labs/jquery-wrap-captions/) but am having problems getting it to work.

When I attempt to validate it, it throws errors with the divs included in the jQuery, however it seems fine when run within the example site.

```
<!-- Caption Wrap script  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.captionme").each(function(i){
        var captiontext = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).wrap("<div class='imgpost'></div>");
        $(this).parent().append("<div class='thecaption'>" + captiontext + "</div>");
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried putting the script in an external file but that doesn't seem to fix it either.

Site is here, the script is pertaining to the image caption (blue section) but the wrap is not working.

http://www.haselden.co.uk/james/docs/

Comment: What does `When I attempt to validate it, it throws errors with the divs included in the jQuery` mean?

Comment: Yours isn't validating the W3C validator, while theirs is, because your JavaScript is embedded within the page. Place it in an external file like you said you tried, and it will validate (or, if it doesn't, at least it won't be due to the JS)

Comment: It obviously means the W3C validator throws an error. How was that confusing? Here's one of the many errors: `Line 26, Column 37: document type does not allow element "div" here`

Comment: When I ran it through the W3C validator is gave me errors pertaining to the <div> inside the jQuery. It said 'document type does not allow element "div" here' - I'm confused as this code is obviously valid as it's used elsewhere fine, yet it doesn't validate or run properly.

Comment: Wrap seems to be working here, using Chrome

Comment: Thanks for making it better explained, perhaps I said it in the wrong way :/ However, the site validates fine if it's external but it still doesn't work! Making me think that that error is the genuine reason for the code not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, visually, is because of the `overflow:auto;` property for `#portfoliowrapper` div. Simply remove `overflow: auto;` or change to `overflow:visible;` and it will display properly.

When you change the overflow, you'll need to clear your floats. Just before `#portfoliowrapper` closes, insert a clear (e.g. `<br clear="all" />` ).

The problem, with the validator, is because the JavaScript is inline. Embed in an external file, and it will pass.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. Now I just need to work out how to put the functionality of the overflow back in.

Comment: Just edited my answer with that explanation :)

Comment: Brilliant thanks :) Have got it all working now. Thanks a lot for your help! (And understanding my apparently poor explanation of things)